# Stripboard as a capacitor

Tags: capacitor, stripboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we build capacitors on a PCB board?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53554/can-we-build-capacitors-on-a-pcb-board)

I have learnt that a capacitor is really just parallel plates. I guess I could use a stripboard as a capacitor by putting links at each end but for a normal 0.1" stripboard like the below is there a formula depending on length and how many elements are across each other? While it seems I couldn't make a large capacitor maybe doing that would be handy for some smaller value, like I see in some small RF bugs?

[image]

Comment: Check the Q linked by Nick. Short answer: yes, but only for a few pF's. Forget anything larger.